# Highlight Read-Along Text (in a storybook type app for iPhone)

Tags: iphone, text, cocos2d-iphone, animated

I love this feature (well, my son loves it), and I would like to implement it in a kid's book app I am doing for iPhone, but I'm clueless where to begin.  I'm using Cocos2d for all the animated sprite/transition stuff, but I'm not sure how to approach highlighting text as it is narrated.

Example:  "Jack and Jill, drank their fill, and were too drunk to go for water."  As the text is narrated (.mp3 plays on each page), the text would be highlighted.  I considered investigating Core animation, but I"m more familiar with Cocs2d at this point (tenuously at best).

If someone has a clue, I'd really appreciate it.

Brendang

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`UIStringDrawing`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) methods to determine the rect needed for the highlight, and then position a semitransparent `UIView` (or whatever cocos2d uses) under your text view. Synchronize with your audio via `NSTimer`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, really appreciate you taking the time to reply.  I've thought about trying to do it manually, but with 800+ words, it didn't seem particularly time efficient.

best,
B.

Comment: You will have to make an index of time codes to highlight rect area (or if you have adjustable text size, substring range), and have your code read that.