# How to perform voice over text in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a set of lines say "She is a little girl". I want to highlight "She" when voice "she" reads, then highlight "is" when voice "is" reads and so on...How to do this.

Comment: [Visit here It Will be helpfull][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691778/highlight-read-along-text-in-a-storybook-type-app-for-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires two things:

1. You're going to have to remember the location of each word as you put it on the screen.
2. You will have to measure the timing of each word in your sound file so the highlights are in sync. There's probably a fancy way to do that by detecting the sound level while it's playing, but if I were doing it, I would simply create a list of timing values and emit the text at those times. I'd test it over and over again until I got it right.